# How to fetch all anchor tag text from div using regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have below `html content` from that I want to fetch all text between `anchor tag`

```
<div class="row mb-xlg"><div class="col-md-12">
<div class="heading heading-border heading-middle-border"><h3>Compatible Models</h3></div>
<div class="row show-grid">
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="/model/SFSPC19S80/_/_/Sanyo/PC19S80/" title="Sanyo PC19S80 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC19S80</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="/model/SFSPC25580/_/_/Sanyo/PC25580/" title="Sanyo PC25580 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC25580</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="/model/SFSPC25S80/_/_/Sanyo/PC25S80/" title="Sanyo PC25S80 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC25S80</a></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><a href="/model/SFSPC27S80/_/_/Sanyo/PC27S80/" title="Sanyo PC27S80 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC27S80</a></div>
</div></div></div>
```

I have below regular expression which returns all text between `anchor tag`

```
<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>+
```

Tested on [this website](https://regex101.com/r/HQFU8j/1)

Result  -

```
Full match  `<a href="/model/SFSPC25580/_/_/Sanyo/PC25580/" title="Sanyo PC25580 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC25580</a>`
Group 1.    `PC25580`
Match 3
Full match  `<a href="/model/SFSPC25S80/_/_/Sanyo/PC25S80/" title="Sanyo PC25S80 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC25S80</a>`
Group 1.    `PC25S80`
Match 4
Full match  `<a href="/model/SFSPC27S80/_/_/Sanyo/PC27S80/" title="Sanyo PC27S80 Remote Control (Pc-27s80)">PC27S80</a>`
Group 1.    `PC27S80`
```

But I want to add `Compatible Models` word condition like

```
<h3>Compatible Models<\/h3>.*?<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>+
```

In this condition it returns only first anchor tag result. 
How can I achieve all anchor tag text result and store in an `array`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for this. Instead you should use a DOM Parser:

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The next link just contains an excellent answer why you shouldn't use regex:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: How to get same result with DOM Parser. Can you please explain